# Show $T_k(G)=G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G = C_n$ is an abelian $p$-group (so that $n = p^a$ for some $a$). Show that $T_k(G) = G$ if $a ≤ k$ and $T_k(G) = C_{p^k}$, otherwise.

$T_k(G)=\{g \in G : o(g) \, \,|\, \, p^k \}$

---

If $a \le k$: I first tried to see what happens when we set $a=k$. We just get that the order of every element in $T$ is a factor of $n$ but I don't see how we can deduce anything from that. It does seem a bit obvious that this would make it be equal to $G$ but I cant write anything down to prove it.

Please help.

Comment: The notation $\;C_n\;$ can be a little confusing as many times it is used to denote the cyclic (usually, multiplicative) group of order $\;n\;$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\;|G|=p^a\;$ , we have that for any

$$\;x\in G\;,\;\;x^{p^a}=1\implies \text{ord}\,(x)\,\mid\,p^a\,\mid\,p^k\implies\text{ord}\,(x)\,\mid\,p^k\;,\;\;\text{for}\;\;a\le k$$

Fill in details now and complete the argument.

Comment: After what you wrote, then $x \in T$ so $G \subseteq T$. Let $x \in T$. Then $x^{p^k}=1$ take the power of $p^a/p^k$ to both sides and then $x^{p^a}=1 \iff o(x)|p^a$ so does that mean $x \in G$?

Comment: @snowman Sorry, I didn't understand. What I showed is that if $\;x\in G\;$ then $\;\text{ord}\,(x)\,\mid\,p^k\implies x\in T_k\implies G=T_k\;$ , as this is true for **any** $\;x\in G\;$ .

Comment: Oh I thought you were trying to show that they were a subset of each other and then equal. I really would have thought you only showed $G \subseteq T_k$...

Comment: @snowman Indeed so as that is the only non-trivial containtment.

Comment: Oh I see. So it is trivial that $T_k \subseteq G$... Could you help on the next part please. When $a>k$

Comment: @snowman I can't since I don't really know what do you mean by $\;C_{p^k}\;$ ...

Comment: OK I guess ill just have to ask my lecturer since he wrote it